# div relatively overlapping

Tags: html, css, positioning, overlap

I have 3 divs. I need to get these overlap but I ***cannot use the absolute positioning***. How can I do this?
I am targeting this to work on a responsive layout(**no fix px values**)

```
    <div id="hold" style="background-color: #CCCCCC;padding: 10px">
        <div id="first" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: red;z-index: 1"></div>
        <div id="sec" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: greenyellow;z-index: 3"></div>
        <div id="third" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: #a3dbec;z-index: 5"></div>
    </div>
```

I used the following css.

```
        #first,#sec,#third{
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `margin-top`:

```
#sec
{
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#third
{
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPq6Z/